# Cannot read hx-includes value on flask view using hx-put

Tags: python, flask, htmx

I cannot read the value of a select element via a htmx PUT `hx-put`, method to the flask view function. The select is in a modal body. I am almost certain I need to read the PUT value from the `request.get_json()` function. The put executes and I can print the `request` object in the view function, but no data.

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 id="muctor" class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h5>
      <h5  class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="dropdown">
          <select id="selected_storage" name="pavvy" class="form-select form-select-sm" aria-label=".form-select-sm example">
              {% for i in items %}
                <option value="{{ i.id }}">{{ i.name }}</option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
  <div><input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Enter your name"></div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button 
        type="button"
        hx-put="{{ url_for('lots_bp.update_storage', id=id) }}"
        hx-include="#selected_storage"
        hx-swap="none"
        hx-headers="{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}"
        hx-trigger="click"
        class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```py
@lots_bp.route("/update_storage/<int:id>", methods=["PUT"])
def update_storage(id: int):
    print(request.get_json())
    return ""
```

This is giving me the following error in the console.

```
SyntaxError: Expected property name or '}' in JSON at position 1 (line 1 column 2)
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at S (htmx.min.js:1:4795)
    at dr (htmx.min.js:1:34354)
    at sr (htmx.min.js:1:31612)
    at ce (htmx.min.js:1:37724)
    at htmx.min.js:1:21402
    at HTMLButtonElement.i (htmx.min.js:1:17838)
y @ htmx.min.js:1
S @ htmx.min.js:1
dr @ htmx.min.js:1
sr @ htmx.min.js:1
ce @ htmx.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ htmx.min.js:1
i @ htmx.min.js:1
htmx.min.js:1 

  PUT http://localhost:5000/lot/update_storage/1 415 (UNSUPPORTED MEDIA TYPE)
ce @ htmx.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ htmx.min.js:1
i @ htmx.min.js:1
htmx.min.js:1 Response Status Error Code 415 from /lot/update_storage/1
```

Comment: The name value of the select has an extra quote - could it be the problem?

Comment: That wasn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

HTMX does not handle json by default (unless you explicitly say to do so via [extentions](https://htmx.org/extensions/json-enc/)). Setting hx-headers will not encode the data itself.

With htmx you can simply handle the data like you would normally do when submiting a form:

```
request.form['pavvy']
```

Answer (score 0):

I did get something working using *hx-vals*

```
 hx-vals="js:{selected_storage: document.querySelector('#selected_storage').value}"
```

view.py

```
request.form.get("selected_storage")
```